# Executing an exe and reading the OutputStream

Tags: java, parsing, ffmpeg, inputstream, apache-commons

I have a program called FFprobe which probes media (files/live streams ... ) and outputs result in different formats , for example :

```
ffprobe.exe -i test.ts -print_format xml -show_programs
```

gives this output :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ffprobe>
    <programs>
        <program program_id="1201" program_num="1201" nb_streams="2" pmt_pid="1000" pcr_pid="2011" start_pts="45394227044" start_time="45394.227044">
            <tag key="service_name" value="Arabica TV"/>
            <tag key="service_provider" value="Nilesat"/>
            <streams>
                <stream index="10" codec_name="mpeg2video" codec_long_name="MPEG-2 video" profile="Main" codec_type="video" codec_time_base="1/50" codec_tag_string="[2][0][0][0]" codec_tag="0x0002" width="720" height="576" has_b_frames="1" sample_aspect_ratio="16:15" display_aspect_ratio="4:3" pix_fmt="yuv420p" level="8" timecode="08:28:54:09" id="0x7db" r_frame_rate="25/1" avg_frame_rate="25/1" time_base="1/90000" start_pts="4085542516" start_time="45394.916844" max_bit_rate="2348000">
                    <disposition default="0" dub="0" original="0" comment="0" lyrics="0" karaoke="0" forced="0" hearing_impaired="0" visual_impaired="0" clean_effects="0" attached_pic="0"/>
                </stream>
                <stream index="4" codec_name="mp2" codec_long_name="MP2 (MPEG audio layer 2)" codec_type="audio" codec_time_base="1/48000" codec_tag_string="[0][0][0][0]" codec_tag="0x0000" sample_fmt="s16p" sample_rate="48000" channels="2" channel_layout="stereo" bits_per_sample="0" id="0xbcf" r_frame_rate="0/0" avg_frame_rate="0/0" time_base="1/90000" start_pts="4085480434" start_time="45394.227044" bit_rate="384000">
                    <disposition default="0" dub="0" original="0" comment="0" lyrics="0" karaoke="0" forced="0" hearing_impaired="0" visual_impaired="0" clean_effects="0" attached_pic="0"/>
                </stream>
            </streams>
        </program> 
... more programs
```

to retrieve this info in java i used ProcessBuilder and a scanner , and then id write to a file once the result is ok ... but it wasnt :

```
 Process proc = new ProcessBuilder("ffprobe.exe","-i", ... same arguments );
 Scanner sc = new Scanner (proc.getInputStream()) // im 100% sure its not errorStream
 while(sc.hasNext()){
   System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
 }
```

the app just hangs with no output , i know its hanging cuz the process is still running and scanner has next , but , i don't know why it would do that ?If i execute the same in cmd i would get good result and ofc i can write to file with ">"

Ive tried it w/o the -print_format option , which gives the info in a plain text on the errorstream(i know its error cuz i was able to write with 2> not >> ) , and i was able to read the error stream in java , but its not meant for parsing cuz very very un-organized .

```
   Input #0, mpegts, from 'PBR_REC_20140426094852_486.ts':
  Duration: 00:13:34.30, start: 7791.344722, bitrate: 42154 kb/s
  Program 1201 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Arabica TV
      service_provider: Nilesat
    Stream #0:19[0x7db]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], max. 2348 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:3[0xbcf]: Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 384 kb/s
  Program 1202 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : NBN
      service_provider: NILESAT
    Stream #0:10[0x7d1]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], max. 2600 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:11[0xbba](eng): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 125 kb/s
  Program 1203 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Heya TV
      service_provider: NILESAT
    Stream #0:5[0x7d2]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], max. 2600 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:6[0xbbc](eng): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, mono, s16p, 125 kb/s
  Program 1204  ... more programs
```

now it might seem organized and "parse-able" and i actually made a parser that worked to some point , but sometimes it doesnt stick to this structure and ruins the whole parsing, its why i need a xml/json ...

The -print_format im sure outputs to outputstream.

Im not asking for help on how to use FFprobe as thats not this place's purpose , Im asking why am i not being able to get the output stream from java while it is definitely outputting if i execute in windows .

I also tried apache commons-exec as i know processbuilder can be a pain ,it did execute perfectly and showed in System.in (black for intput and red for error), but getting the stream with apache is something i couldn't understand , i tried this [example](http://gnujava.com:8000/board/article_view.jsp?article_no=5306&board_no=1&table_cd=EPAR01&table_no=01)

The xml parser i already taken care of , simply put i just need to execute that first command from java and read the output , but for some reason its not working .

Comment: Your ffprobe process may be waiting for standard input.  The easiest way to fix this is by calling `redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT)` on your ProcessBuilder before starting the process.

Comment: @VGR , that didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I generally use variations of this utility method:

```
public static void runProcess(ProcessBuilder pb) throws IOException {
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = pb.start();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Even if you don't want to print the error stream you need to consume it otherwise it will block the process. In which case you would need to consume it in a separate thread and only print the input stream from the main thread.

Comment: ill give this a try but how is this different from what im doin ?

Comment: well it did work , but it's outputting error and inputstream (mixed up) , and can you please explain how it is different from what i did , basically u used a BufferedReader , i used a scanner

Comment: @vlatkozelka does your version work if you redirect the error stream? Even if you don't want to print the error stream you need to consume it otherwise it will block the process. In which case you would need to consume it in a separate thread and only print the input stream from the main thread.

Comment: yes , that worked ! i started a new Thread to consume the error stream while inputstream is being read , it worked perfectly :) I guess consuming error is a must , that i did not know... could you please edit your answer ? just for other people