# How to get Exec Output in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have been trying to get this right, but with no success.
I am executing a command to get a ping result, then store it in a variable, but when I show the variable in a TOAST it always displays "NULL".

Here's my code:

```
fun pingthis(): String? {
    try
    {
        //execute the command
        val pingprocess: Process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 -s 64 $host")
        pingprocess.waitFor()
        val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(pingprocess.inputStream))

        //read the result
        val logger: StringBuilder = StringBuilder()
        var line: String? = ""
        while (line != null) {
            line = bufferedReader.readLine()
            logger.append(line + "\n")
        }

        pingResult = logger.toString()

    } catch (e: IOException) {}
 return pingResult 
 }
```

as you can see, "pingResult" always ALWAYS returns NULL. I don't know why. What have I done wrong?

Comment: You execute a process, wait for it to finish and then try to read its output - but the process is already terminated so you don't get anything... https://stackoverflow.com/a/26127342/829571

Comment: I have the removed the waitFor expression.  I still get null values from BufferedReader. How do I exactly read outputs from command exec ? I am clueless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should've probably guessed this on my own but I was not focused at all lol; It took me three days to know that I am pinging without internet permissions on my app. Which is, if you ask me, very stupid.

The code above works very well for executing ping command and parsing the output, but I always got null because the ping command won't even run if I had no internet permissions.

I added network permissions to my Android Manifest and it's working perfectly.

Also thanks to assylias's comment above. You shouldn't do "process.waitFor()' then read the output, because the process would already be terminated.